# My localized strings are not detected

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I'm trying to localize my strings in Xcode 4, but the only thing I get are the keys, not the values.

I've localized the strings using `NSLocalizedString(key, comment)`. 
I've generated the file Localizable.strings using genstrings from the command line.
I've dragged and dropped Localizable.strings from Finder to Xcode (into the Resources folder).
I've localized Localizable.strings and added the appropriate countries.
I've made sure the encoding is UTF-16.
I've translated the different Localizable.strings for each country.
I've rechecked that the encoding is still UTF-16.
I've checked that each statement in Localizable.strings ends with a semi colon.

Still not working.

Any idea of what I've missed?

*edit*

Here a part of my Localizable.strings

```
/* Text displayed on the comment button if there are more than one comment. */
"CommentButtonTextPlural" = "comments";

/* Text displayed on the comment button if there is exacly one comment. */
"CommentButtonTextSingular" = "comment";

/* Text displayed on the post button. */
"CommentViewPostButtonLabel" = "Post";

/* Default text displayed in the area where the user types in a comment. */
"CommentViewWriteAComment" = "Write a comment...";

/* Error message explaining that a document isn't viewable on the user's device. */
"DocumentRendererStatusDetailedErrorText" = "This document is not viewable on this device.";

/* Message explaining that the document is downloading. */
"DocumentRendererStatusDownloadingText" = "Downloading...";
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your Localizable.strings? If not all, at least the header and the first fews keys.

Comment: Done. I've added part of the file with english translations (duh!). :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working.

What I did was remove the Localizable.strings (from the harddrive, I haven't touched the files located in the xx.lproj folders) file which genstrings created for me and removed the app-file on my device.

Comment: +1 for deleting the app from the device and reinstalling. My app didn't use the localized strings until I did that.

Answer (score 1):

You may be putting the Localizable.strings file in the wrong location so it's using the default translations.

When you add a new language, Xcode creates a new folder in your App Directory which ends in .lproj (so for English it would be en.lproj) and that is where your Localizable.strings file for English should be.

If you want a French one, add the French Language and Xcode will generate a fr.lproj directory and that is where the French Localizable.strings file will be located.

From your description, putting it in the Resources Folder is incorrect.

Comment: I've added the original Localizable.strings in Resources (inside Xcode that is). When I localize the file Xcode creates the xx.lproj folders and puts a copy of Localizable.strings in each. I have a xx.lproj folder (and a .strings file in each) for each of the seven languages I plan to support.

Answer (score 0):

Your Localization should look like the following:

[image]

and on your desktop:

[image]

Comment: Xcode4 never created the App Resources folder for me nor the Localization folder. However I created the folders and moved Localizable.strings accordingly. Still doesn't work though.

Comment: That is a group that I created, you should at least have the Localization group though with the Localizable.strings.

Comment: If your project looks similar to my screenshot, and you have used `NSLocalizedString` correctly, then it should work properly.

Comment: Thanks, managed to get it working now. However the Localization group doesn't seem to be required for it to work. Xcode didn't create it either when I localized Localization.string.

Comment: Localizable.strings is what's required.

Comment: What solved the issue was deleting the Localization.strings that genstrings generated. Somehow that file override the localized versions.

Comment: Yup, thank you for taking the time. :-)
It might've been caused by the existing .app-file too. I deleted them at the same time as the .strings-file.

Xcode overall feels kinda buggy due to these small issues...